# Updating and creating entries with PHP and DynamoDB

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have a string set on one of my DynamoDB tables.

This code adds a new item to the string set and works great

```
$update = $client->updateItem ( array (
  'TableName' => 'myTable',
  'Key' => array (
    'rep_num' => array (
      'S' => $id_num
    )
  ),
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
    ':transaction_ids' => array(
        'SS' => array($transaction_id)
    )
  ),
  'UpdateExpression' => 'ADD transaction_ids :transaction_ids'
));
```

My problem is, it only works if the key `transaction_ids` already exists on an item.

How can I change this code to also create the key on an existing item if one doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

If the item doesn't have the `transaction_ids`, it should create the attribute and add the value to it.

If the item has the attribute `transaction_ids`, it should add the value to it as long as the data type of new value matches with the existing `SS` attribute data type.

Refer this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_updateItem)

> If the existing data type is a set, and if Value is also a set, then
>   Value is appended to the existing set. For example, if the attribute
>   value is the set [1,2], and the ADD action specified [3], then the
>   final attribute value is [1,2,3]. An error occurs if an ADD action is
>   specified for a set attribute and the attribute type specified does
>   not match the existing set type.
>
> Both sets must have the same primitive data type. For example, if the
>   existing data type is a set of strings, Value must also be a set of
>   strings.

**I have tested with JavaScript API. It works as expected. It should work in PHP as well.**

**Sample code:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "ADD #transaction_ids :transaction_ids ",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#transaction_ids' : 'transaction_ids',

        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {':transaction_ids' :  docClient.createSet(["3"])},
```